# How do I release my soundPool media?

Tags: android, android-fragments, release, soundpool, ondestroy

My app keeps on crashing due to memory overload. Before I had multiple sound pools but now I have changed this so I only use one sound pool for the entire app. This is called 'Clubb1'. However my app is still crashing after opening the third fragment, I think I need to release the sounds once they have finished playing so that the memory is not taken up. Am I right? If so how do I do it? I'm new to all this coding so I'm a bit confused.

Here is my first fragment:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment  {


SoundPool Clubb1;
int clubb1Id;

int clubb2Id;

int clubb3Id;

int clubb4Id;

int clubb5Id;

int clubb6Id;

int clubb7Id;

int clubb8Id;

int clubb9Id;

int clubb10Id;








@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState
) {

    Clubb1 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
    clubb1Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb1, 1);

    clubb2Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb2, 1);

    clubb3Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb3, 1);

    clubb4Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb4, 1);

    clubb5Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb5, 1);

    clubb6Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb6, 1);

    clubb7Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb7, 1);

    clubb8Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb8, 1);

    clubb9Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb9, 1);

    clubb10Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb10, 1);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);

    Button buttonA = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
    Button buttonB = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
    Button buttonC = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
    Button buttonD = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
    Button buttonE = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonE);
    Button buttonF = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonF);
    Button buttonG = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonG);
    Button buttonH = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonH);
    Button buttonI = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonI);
    Button buttonJ = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonJ);

    View.OnClickListener ocl = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.buttonA:
                    //A clicked
                    Clubb1.play(clubb1Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonB:
                    //B clicked
                    Clubb1.play(clubb2Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonC:
                    //C clicked
                    Clubb1.play(clubb3Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonD:
                    //D clicked
                    Clubb1.play(clubb4Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonE:
                    //E clicked
                    Clubb1.play(clubb5Id, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonF:
                    //F clicked
                    Clubb1.play(clubb6Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonG:
                    //G clicked
                    Clubb1.play(clubb7Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonH:
                    //H clicked
                    Clubb1.play(clubb8Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonI:
                    //I clicked
                    Clubb1.play(clubb9Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonJ:
                    //J clicked
                    Clubb1.play(clubb10Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    buttonA.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonB.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonC.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonD.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonE.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonF.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonG.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonH.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonI.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    buttonJ.setOnClickListener(ocl);

    return rootView;
}}
```

Where and what do I put into my code to relieve the amount of memory I am using? and to stop my app crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Call `release()` on your Clubb1 `SoundPool` instance where and when you want to release memory used by your `SoundPool`.

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener ,  SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener {

    SoundPool Clubb1;
    Integer currentBtnId;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);
        Clubb1 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);

        Button buttonA = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
        Button buttonB = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
        Button buttonC = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
        Button buttonD = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
        Button buttonE = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonE);
        Button buttonF = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonF);
        Button buttonG = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonG);
        Button buttonH = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonH);
        Button buttonI = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonI);
        Button buttonJ = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonJ);

        buttonA.setTag(R.raw.clubb1);
        buttonB.setTag(R.raw.clubb2);
        buttonC.setTag(R.raw.clubb3);
        buttonD.setTag(R.raw.clubb4);
        buttonE.setTag(R.raw.clubb5);
        buttonF.setTag(R.raw.clubb6);
        buttonG.setTag(R.raw.clubb7);
        buttonH.setTag(R.raw.clubb8);
        buttonI.setTag(R.raw.clubb9);
        buttonJ.setTag(R.raw.clubb10);

        buttonA.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonB.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonC.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonD.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonE.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonF.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonG.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonH.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonI.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonJ.setOnClickListener(this);

        Clubb1.setOnLoadCompleteListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(currentBtnId != null){
            Clubb1.release();
        }

        currentBtnId = v.getId();
        int sampleId = (Integer) v.getTag();
        Clubb1.load(getActivity(), sampleId, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
        switch (currentBtnId){
            case R.id.buttonE:
                //E clicked
                soundPool.play(sampleId, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1);
                break;
            default:
                soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put it in your `OnClick` listener, with a flag seeing if previous song is playing and if is then call `release`

Comment: what would be the code that i would need to write? sorry I'm not very good at this

Comment: See updated answer, rather cast to object Integer than primitive int.

Comment: when i run the app it only plays the first button sound once and then no other sound plays again, also when i add this to my 2nd fragment the app just crashes before it begins

Comment: well i assumed each button you would select and it plays a different sound, in that case just call `release` in `onDestroyView` of your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

For proper loading and to avoid lagging when the fragment created put each loading code inside its proper onClick place like this :

```
 View.OnClickListener ocl = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonA:
                //A clicked
                clubb1Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb1, 1);
                Clubb1.play(clubb1Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonB:
                //B clicked
                clubb2Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb2, 1);
                Clubb1.play(clubb2Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                break;
             //And so on ....
 }
 }
```

Then when you finish release them in the proper way by calling `release()` to your `SoundPool`

Comment: How would I write the release() for my sound pool?